Cannot delete from source during transfer job using Google Storage Transfer Service
Here is the context of my issue:
I have a VM with a mounted POSIX file system. WIthin the file system, I've created a directory called "test" (along with some files within) under the user "main" (does not have root access) to be used as the source directory for Google Storage Transfer Service. What I want to do is start a transfer job that transfers from the source to a bucket and then delete the files from the source directory.
After configuring and installing the transfer agent (rootless; using terraform script) under the same account, "main", I proceeded to start the transfer job process and fortunately it is able to transfer successfully and delete files from the source with no issues.
Another user called "alternate" from the same group called "together" that "main" is also apart of has created another directory called "attempt" to be transferred to the bucket as well.
So...
drwxrwxr--.  1    main        together    test
drwxrwxr--.  1    alternate   together    attempt

When I start another transfer job to have the "attempt" directory transferred over, it fails. It actually appears that the transfer of the source files to the bucket occurs BUT the agent cannot delete any of the source files

After making sure they are in the same group and the directory and files of "attempt" have the right permissions (RW) for "main" to delete, it still looks like there's an issue.
Like I mentioned previously, when everything is done against the "main" account (creating directories, files, transfers jobs), everything works smoothly. But when another user tries to move their directories or files into the source directory for the transfer, they cannot be deleted.
I would also like to note that I configured and am using an IAM service account in GCP with the correct roles because it works in one of the end-to-end test scenarios successfully, noted above.
Can someone please help me shed some light on the issue?
